# Make vimscript bang command interpret vim variables

Tags: vim

I'm writing a vimscript tool to allow me to look at git diffs from within my current vim session by calling git difftool  .  This works fine when I hard-code the two sha values, but fails when I try to specify them as variables.  I wrote a 2 line shell script do_git_difftool to explore the problem, and it shows that instead of passing the values, the literal variable names "l:left_sha" and "l:right_sha" are passed, even though they are correctly interpreted in the echom on the previous line.  What gives?

```
function! s:GitDiff (...)

     let l:the_count = 1
     :let l:syscommand = "get_sha back " . l:the_count
     :let l:left_sha = system(l:syscommand)
     :let l:syscommand = "get_sha top"
     :let l:right_sha = system(l:syscommand)
     echom "sha values"  l:left_sha l:right_sha

     :silent !git difftool l:left_sha l:right_sha
     :silent !do_git_difftool l:left_sha l:right_sha

endfunction

# in a bash script named do_git_difftool 
echo args are $1 and $2 > thelog
git difftool $1 $2

  in the log file I see: 

args are l:left_sha and l:right_sha
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: yes. You should probably use

```
exec "!git_difftool " . l:left_sha . " " . l:right_sha
```

Bang commands will pass everything after them to the terminal without vim touching it (since shell commands don't use vim syntax). To get variable interpretation, make it an exec command to create the bang command.

Edit:

If you need it silent, just prepend the line with `silent`

Comment: This works, thanks.  As I might have expected, after I quit the diffs, I get prompted with 'Press Enter or type command to continue" which :silent would remove when used in my original try.  Is there any way to do the same in the context of 'execute'.

Comment: prepending with silent does that.